# inserting image into codes in chess game c#

Tags: c#, image, chess

i asked a question about chess game 2days ago,and a friend suggest me the code below,and i have question about it.[it was this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098632/communicate-between-king-image-in-form-and-the-algorithm-for-that-in-chess-game-c)

please see:
private image Displayimage;

i don't know how should i put images from pieces of chess game in it,and where should i put it?
     class PiecePosition
    {

```
    public enum ChessColor
    {
        White,
        Black,
    }
    public class ChessPiece
    {
        private Image DisplayedImage;
        private ChessColor DisplayedColor;
        private Point CurrentSquare;
        private Point[] ValidMoves;
        public ChessPiece(Image image, ChessColor color)
        {
            DisplayedImage = image;
            DisplayedColor = color;
        }
    }
    public class KingPiece : ChessPiece
    {

        public KingPiece(Image image, ChessColor color)
            : base(image, color)
        {
            ValidMoves[0] = new Point(0, -1);    //  Up 1
            ValidMoves[1] = new Point(1, -1);    //  Up 1, Right 1
            ValidMoves[2] = new Point(1, 0);     //  Right 1

            ValidMoves[7] = new Point(-1, -1);  //  Left 1, Up 1
        }

    }
    public class Board
    {

        private ChessPiece[,] square;
        private int SquareWidth;    //  Number of pixels wide
        private int SquareHeight;    //  Number of pixels high



    }
}
```

Comment: You already have a `private Image DisplayedImage;` so what is the question here?

Comment: On a somewhat unrelated note, I'd mark the ChessPiece class as an 'abstract' class because you'll never want to create an instance of a generic chess piece. You would still be able to use ChessPiece as a base class to refer to any of the specific types of piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wondering how you can compile the images along with your source code and then access them, the easiest way is to add the images to your project using [Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). This allows you to easily add external files as embedded resources in your project that will be compiled directly into your executable.

**To add a resource to your project, follow these steps:**

1. In the Solution Explorer,
   right-click the project you want to
   add a resource to. Select
   "Properties" option and click the
   "Resources" tab.
2. Looking at the toolbar on the top of the Resources window, the first button allows you to select the type of resources that you want to add or edit in your project. In your case, you want to add an image, so select "Image" from the list of options in the drop-down menu.
3. Then click the drop-down arrow next to the "Add Resource" button. From here, you can either add a new image (which you can draw and edit from within Visual Studio) or add an existing image that you already have on your computer.

**Now that you've added resources to your project file, you can use them in your code like this** (all of the access details are handled automatically by the ResourceManager class):

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap kingImage = MyChessGame.Properties.Resources.KingImage;
KingPiece kingPiece = new KingPiece(kingImage, ChessColor.White);
```

Comment: i did this,but it still say:The type or namespace name 'Image' could not be found.should i define any class or etc for Image?

Comment: Your project needs to have a reference to System.Drawing, but it should have this by default.

Comment: It says that where you declared `private Image DisplayedImage;` in the `ChessPiece` class? What "Image" is it referring to?

Comment: that problem solved with adding system.drawing,and now it has this error:chess6.PiecePosition.ChessPiece.ValidMoves' is inaccessible due to its protection

Comment: i changed private point[] ValidMoves to public and it Apparently solved(is it correct?)another compile error is for the  image i selected for king,see this line:KingPiece kingPiece = new KingPiece(siyahsah1,ChessColor.Black);   it gives error:A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'chess6.PiecePosition.KingPiece.siyahsah1'

Comment: The variables in the base class ChessPiece are declared private, which means they can only be accessed from that class, but you're trying to assign values to them from the derived class KingPiece. That's why you're getting that error. You need to create property accessors in the base class that are declared public. It's a lot to try and explain here. I recommend picking up a good book about programming in C#. Maybe see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795/recommended-books-for-learning-c

Comment: It's difficult for me to track down some of those compiler errors without having the full source code in front of me to see what names you're using for variables, etc. Maybe consider posting a new question if you're still having trouble after playing with it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify image location (resource preferably).
First, Add the image to your resources. Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28VS.80%29.aspx) from MSDN for more info. Then do something like:

```
var KingImage = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.KingImage;
var kingPiece = new KingPiece(KingImage, Color.Black);
```